# Firestore security rules for `list` request

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

**In the Firestore security rules, is it possible to check certain document fields when using a `list` query?**

Using Angular, I want to retrieve a single document from the `userprofiles` collection using its `username` property as follows:

```
let userprofile = this.afs.collection( 'userprofiles', ref => 
ref.where('username', '==', username ).limit(1);
```

I want this query to be allowed by the Firestore security rules, if either:

- the userprofile is published, or
- the userprofile is unpublished, but the corresponding user is logged-in

Here are my Firestore security rules:

```
match /userprofiles/{userprofileId} {

    allow list:  if( resource.data.published==true || (    
                     resource.data.published==false &&
                     resource.data.uid==request.auth.uid )
                 );
    }
}
```

*For context, I am using the exact same rule to allow `get` request, which works fine. However, the query in the above example causes a `list` request, not a `get`. And in that case, these rules do not permit the query. I am getting `Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.`*

I remember reading something along the lines of that for list queries, the rules must allow either all or no documents, which in my case doesn't apply. So I sort of understand why it doesn't work.

**My question is, can I change something to make it work for my query? Or is this not possible? Any ideas for workarounds? (apart from the obvious "query by document-id" or "make username the document-id")**

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I have run into a case where i can get the document directly via id, but when I do a where query that checks for id == MYID (which is a list with one result) it fails with a permission denied.

Answer (score 21):

In order to allow "list" for queries, the query parameters must match the security rules. Please refer to [the documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_a_field)

Your query would need to include the published==true statement:

```
let userprofile = this.afs.collection( 'userprofiles', ref => 
ref.where('published', '==', true).where('username', '==', username ).limit(1);
```

And your rules could be simplified to:

```
match /userprofiles/{userprofileId} {

    allow list: if resource.data.published==true || 
                   resource.data.uid==request.auth.uid;
}
```

Note that the query would only list the published userprofiles. I don't think it would be possible to query for "published==true" OR matching the uid condition at once, your code would need to query twice.

Comment: Totally missed that part of the doc. Your answer ended a long and frustrating session of troubleshooting, thank you! [I'm not the OP]

Comment: How would we match an or statement from security rule if it's not allowed in queries ? For example how to match this rule : `allow list: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.receiversUids || request.auth.uid == resource.data.senderUid;`

Comment: See the fact that it is basically impossible to find this in the docs via docs/google search, shows how bad the docs rlly are. I actually found out about this behaviour after hours of error and trial, and as soon as I found the solution, the docs and this post both popped up in my searches xDDD once u know how to google a firebase problem, u already know the solution

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's a little to late for this question. But I recently are facing this kind of problem, and I've done some work upon @rednuht's answer. Here's what I've done.

As @Ben mention, I also want a post with published and unpublished. And everyone can get published posts, but only author can get unpublished posts.

And thanks to @rednuht's answer, the rules can simplify to:

```
match /userprofiles/{userprofileId} {

    allow list: if resource.data.published==true || 
                   resource.data.uid==request.auth.uid;
}
```

But what @rednuht said need to query twice in the last is quit not correct. You can query all your posts at once ( both published and unpublished ). Just change the query to

```
// this query can get all my posts at once.
// WARNING: myUsername can only put the current username can't query other users
let userprofile = this.afs.collection( 'userprofiles', ref => 
ref.where('username', '==', myUsername ).limit(1);

// querying other user's published posts
let userprofile = this.afs.collection( 'userprofiles', ref => 
ref.where('published', '==', true).where('username', '==', myUsername ).limit(1);
```

Answer (score -6):

My be late, but statement like this works in my case

```
match /userprofiles/{userprofileId} {
    allow read: if resource.data.published==true;
    }
}
match /userprofiles/{userprofileId} {
    allow read: if resource.data.uid==request.auth.uid;
    }
}
```